# Cypress not opening URL and throwing error

Tags: cypress

I am trying to open a URL using cypress but it is giving error in response
{"error_code":"E0020000","trace_id":"c2ecd944c52b870ca9d4a014f821f4cd"}

Not sure what this error is.
I am using cy.visit("") to launch the URL. I tried this on different browsers but it is giving this error. Please help me with same

Comment: Also i checked the network tab and one of the login request is throwing 500 internal server error. but when I try to navigate manually then it works fine

Comment: If you use cy.visit("") in your test then value of baseUrl from cypress.json is being used.

Comment: @TomaszWojciechowski not sure what u r trying to say here. requesting to please elaborate .

Comment: Please check information about baseUrl on https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration - if you use cy.visit("") in your tests then value for baseUrl in use.